# UAP Flyout blocks and handles other events

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In Windows 10, VS2015 with latest updates working in a XAML C# UAP. If I have Button1 and Button2 I add a Tapped event to Button2 and a Flyout to Button1. If I open the flyout in Button1 and try to click Button2, it first closes the flyout but does not raise the Tapped Event in Button2. I want whenever I have a flyout opened and click anywhere on the screen to raise any events in background elements. The flyout is capturing all the events until it is closed. How can I avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you've seen is by design.

Ref [Dialogs and flyouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs):

> Unlike a dialog, a flyout can be quickly dismissed by tapping or clicking somewhere outside the flyout, pressing the Escape key or Back button, resizing the app window, or changing the device's orientation.

A flyout is a lightweight contextual popup, when the flyout is open, it will block user interactions. And when users tap or click somewhere outside the flyout, it will close. Flyout is designed to act like this, we can not avoid this behavior.

If this is not what you want, I'd suggest you try with some other control. For example, you can put the content of the flyout into a panel alongside "Button1" and use the `Tapped`/`Click` event of "Button1" to control the [Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility.aspx) of the panel to show or hide the content.

Comment: I used at the end the PopUp control, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda Yeah, Popup control is a good alternative.